# Define type of inheritance in a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I like to define the type (:_type) of an mongoid object with inheritence straight from a form.

Defining the type of and object is quite simpel:

```
shapes.build({ x: 0, y: 0 }, Circle)
```

But now I was wondering if it's possible to build such an object automatically by using the params in a form. Something like this:

```
<%= form_for :shapes do |s| %>
    <%= s.text_field(:x) %>
    <%= s.text_field(:y) %>
    <%= t.hidden_field(:_type, value: "Circle") %>
<% end %>
```

And then use something like:

```
Shapes.new(params[:shapes])
```

Defining a _type value in a hidden field seems not possible. Any ideas?

Comment: Why does it seem not possible?

Comment: It just won't set the _type param. Seems protected or something.

Comment: Did you define it as `attr_accessible`? You should also be able to handle it via a helper if you can't set it directly.

Comment: Defined the `attr_accesible` only as `:type` and not `:_type`. Fixed that, and it now defines the _type only it doesn't handle it the way it should if I build a new instance from it. It keeps getting the main instance instead of the object of that type just defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like the following

```
model = params[:shapes][:_type].to_s.classify.constantize

model.new(params[:shapes])
```

The first bit takes the string and converts it to the actually class, so "Circle" becomes Circle, if you get what I am saying. The next part calls new on the actually class instead of the parent of that class. That way the correct type is set.

[The docs for constantize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-constantize)

Comment: That's a step closer to it. I can now define the :_type of the instance with `constantize` but still it handles it like its the main object. The actual code differs from the example I gave. In my actual problem I have a set of embedded objects and thus embedded forms, I was hopping that I didn't had to break down the whole params tree. Any thoughts about that? Can't I do something like: `<%= form_for :shapes(_type: 'Circle') do |s| %>`